# Can My Employer Charge Me a Fee to Get a Mailed Check Instead of Direct Deposit?

Tags: united-states, fees, employment, paycheck, utah

I have preferred to receive paper checks instead of direct deposit, as I find it easier to keep track of.

However, my employer has now announced that there will be a (quite large) fee associated with not doing direct deposit.  I can understand maybe covering postage and the cost of an envelope, but this is *much* more than that.

**Is my employer allowed to do this?**  (If it varies by state, I'm in Utah.)

<sup>Note: The only reference I could find is [this](https://www.paycor.com/resource-center/can-i-require-my-employees-to-use-direct-deposit): "Employers aren’t allowed to charge employees fees based on payment method."  However, I'm looking for a more primary and complete source.</sup>

Comment: My employer does the same (in FL), and as they are a 50000+ people employer and always stay far on the safe side of the law, I am rather sure it's legal for them to do that. - The high cost comes probably from the need to have a secure system running only for the 2 or 3 they need to handle.

Comment: Something the other answers did not address is they are probably simply passing on the cost of generating a paper check from their payroll processor.  It is unlikely they are viewing this as a profit center.

Comment: Could you simply print the pay stub they provide you?

Answer (score 5):

I have worked for several different companies over the years.

Besides deduction for the expected thing: taxes, social security, insurance, retirement. I have also worked for companies that had a  process for including in the deductions money for: charity (United Way), US Saving Bonds, A loan program for a new computer, purchasing of additional vacation day. I know of other companies where deductions are made for union dues and uniforms.

While I am not a Lawyer, if did find this part of the [Utah labor code](http://le.utah.gov/xcode/Title34/Chapter28/34-28-S3.html) interesting:

> (4)   If a deduction is made from the wages paid, the employer shall, on
>   each regular payday, furnish the employee with a statement showing the
>   total amount of each deduction.

and

> (6)   An employer may not withhold or
>   divert part of an employee's wages unless:
>
> (a) the employer is required to withhold or divert the wages by:
>
> (i)    court order; or
>
> (ii)   state or federal law;
>
> (b)    the employee expressly authorizes the deduction in writing;

Which implies to me that if they tell an employee that there i a charge of X to get a paper check, and you agree to that in writing, then it would be allowed.

The cost of generating a paper check can be beyond the cost of postage. according to the [Social Security administration in 2013](https://www.ssa.gov/legislation/testimony_061913.html):

> Electronic payments are beneficial for the public and more efficient
>   for the agency. They are inexpensive – it costs the government about
>   $1.25 to issue a paper check; conversely, it costs only about $0.09 to
>   pay a federal benefit electronically. In addition, electronic payments
>   are significantly less likely to be lost or stolen compared to paper
>   checks.

Utah law also requires a pay stub:

> (5)(a) on the day on which the employer pays an employee, give the employee a
>   written or electronic pay statement

Answer (score 0):

You should probably ask a lawyer.

Looking at the [Utah labor code](http://le.utah.gov/xcode/Title34/Chapter28/34-28-S3.html), I see this:

> An employer may not withhold or divert part of an employee's wages unless: ...

Your situation doesn't seem to fall under the exception.

An employer, if qualifies, may **require** you to accept direct deposit, though (same page, subsection 3).

Comment: I think subsection (b) under (6) would cover the employer. If the employee requests a paper check, part of that would be agreeing to withholding the fee for the paper check.